# Force Subview to fill parent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have some subviews that I place inside each of my tab bar's view controllers. Right now I'm sizing it with a pixel count but it only works on the iPhone 4 and 4s and not the iPhone 5 because of the longer screen size. I could check for the device and then size it that way but I feel like there has to be an easier way to do this.

```
viewController1.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
```

I colored the subview yellow so it's easier to see.

[image]

Comment: Normally you shouldn't be adjusting frames of a UIViewController view explicitly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You should NOT change frame of tabbar's content view controller's view. `UITabBar` takes itself care of sizing the child view controller's frame properly.
2. If you want to add subview to content view controller (controller under some tab) and make that view to always automatically resize with the controllers main view (`self.view`), you can use combination of `superview`s frame and autoresizing.

Example code (you can do this in `- (void)viewDidLoad` for example):

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Comment: This worked almost all the way. I now have a ~20-30px white space on the top of the view right below the nav bar

Comment: How does your views structure looks like? This code must be working properly. Do you use translucent navigation bar? Are you sure you are not making some manual adjustments to the frame? Also: do you really need to have custom view with the same size as the `self.view`? Can you just use `self.view`?

Comment: if( ! __MY_STATIC_CDVViewController ) {
        __MY_STATIC_CDVViewController = [CDVViewController new];
        __MY_STATIC_CDVViewController.useSplashScreen = NO;
        //__MY_STATIC_CDVViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
        
    }
    else
    {
        
    }
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    
    [self.view addSubview: __MY_STATIC_CDVViewController.view];

Comment: What does `CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)` do? Use `self.view.bounds` instead

Comment: I think you're right about the status bar. The gap is the same height as it.

Comment: Why are you creating empty view? My code is just the sample! Configure your view like in the sample. Do `__MY_STATIC_CDVViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds; __MY_STATIC_CDVViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` and don't add `view`, its useless

Comment: You're welcome. But still don't get why you just create controller and add its view as subview. You code will still not work very well. You need to add child view controller. Or simplest solution: add your controller as the root view controller of `UINavigationController`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this by setting frame than DO this:

```
[childView setFrame:childView.superview.bounds];
```

Answer (score 1):

The master view in your view controller should already be the size of the usable space on the sceen. In general, if you want a view to be the same size as it's parent, you can use `view.frame = view.superview.frame`, though I doubt that would be a good idea to call on the view controller's view.